# Python Head request with urrlib and proxy doesn't work

Tags: python, https, proxy, tor

I'm failing to do a HEAD request through my local Tor Proxy

```
import httplib
host = 'www.heise.de'
inputfilename="/newsticker/classic/"

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("127.0.0.1", 9151)
conn.set_tunnel(host, 443)
conn.request("HEAD", inputfilename)
res = conn.getresponse()

print res
```

I get a lot of error messages, what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Also, the correct port is 9150 if you are running Tor through the Browser Bundle, otherwise it's 9050 by default.  9051 and 9151 are for control connections to interact with the Tor daemon, not issue requests.

Answer (score 3):

Your Tor proxy is a SOCKS proxy, which isn't supported by httplib.

You can use a recent version of `requests` (which `httplib` recommends to use instead of itself, anyway).

Install `requests` and `pySocks`

Then, you can do:

```
import requests
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'
}

# You need to use the url, not just the host name
url = 'http://www.heise.de'
response = requests.head(url, proxies=proxies)
print(response.headers)

#{'Vary': 'X-Forwarded-Proto, ... 'Last-Modified': 'Sun, 26 Feb 2017 09:27:45 GMT'}
```